# Intro to Analysis, Derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

> Let $p$ be a fixed real number satisfying $0 < p \leq 1.$ Show that $(1+x)^p \leq 1+ x^p$ for all $x\geq 0.$ You may assume that the derivative of $x^p$ is $p x^{p-1} $ if $x>0$.

I tried to use the MVT but it wasn't working out.

I got $p(1+x)^{p-1}=\cfrac{((1+x)^p+1)}{x} \leq px^{p-1}$

which is $(1+x)^p+1\leq px^p$.

and from there I don't see how I can show the result I want. How should I proceed?

Comment: If $(1+x)^p>1+x^p$ for all $p>1$ does that imply this?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = (1+x)^p$ and $g(x) = 1+x^p$ and note that these are continuous functions. Consider instead $g(x) - f(x)$ and it will be sufficient to show that this is nonnegative. Note that $g(0) - f(0) = 0$. Clearly (you've shown this) $g'(x) - f'(x) \ge 0$. Intuitively, you have a function starting at the x-axis and as you move along, its derivative is always nonnegative, so the function should never go below its starting point, namely the x-axis. Can you formalize this?